# AJAX Login Interface

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, authentication

What is the best way to implement a AJAX login portal?
I am creating a login portal like Stack Overflow's that will allow a user to select mutiple methods for logging in to a site.

How do I make the selection AJAX so that for an example if the user uses "site login" then the div or the content of the login panel with AJAX and refresh to a sign in form?

Should I have these in different divs, then do a show or hide with jQuery or is there another method I should be using?

```
<body>
     <ul id="login-options">
          <li>site login</li>
          <li>facebook</li>
          <li>google</li>
          <li>twitter</li>
     </ul>
</body?
```

Comment: What have you tried? This question is not a good fit for SO - asking "what is the best way" to do something is not constructive and leads to debate. Vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach click events to the options first :

```
<ul id="login-options">
      <li id="site">site login</li>
      <li id="facebook">facebook</li>
      <li id="google">google</li>
      <li id="twitter">twitter</li>
 </ul>
```

One method is to add forms in HTML for each login type in a separate div, and hide. On the ajax selector for the option, show the corresponding div.

```
 $("#site").click(function() {

        $("#div_site_login").show();

 });
```

The second is to add the form markup to a div dynamically from inside jQuery.

```
   $("#div_site_login").html('your form here');
```

Comment: @janez00: Your answer is perfect. Thank you!